# I'm having trouble getting file_get_contents() to work on my server

Tags: php

I've got a php file on my server that looks like this:

echo file_get_contents('http://server.com/some.file');

and I get the following error:

Warning: file_get_contents(http://server.com/some.file) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /path/to/php/file on line 6

What's got me confused is that if I link to the/full/server/path instead of http:// it seems to load fine.  Also, I can get it to load content from other domains using http://, just not my own.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you get opening `http://server.com/some.file` directly in a browser?

Comment: the file loads fine in a browser.  It definitely exists and is in place.

Answer (score 0):

As deceze sayd test the path in a browser. It should work the same as in PHP. If the path you write is correct check your URL rewrites (maybe you have them different for the server IP).

Comment: It definitely loads fine in the browser.  No rewrites to speak of.